# Does density affect the gravitational acceleration experienced by an object due to a larger body?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, projectile, vacuum, drag

I know that under a vacuum, the mass of an object does not affect how fast it falls to zero height. I assume that is the same for density? What if there were air resistance?

Sorry for the super simple question, I'm not from STEM; I just want my short story to be scientifically accurate.

Answer (score 1):

In a vacuum the density doesn't affect the acceleration of a falling object.

If there were air resistance the density does matter.

In air a dense ball bearing would fall with a similar acceleration as in a vacuum, but a less dense object, for example a polystyrene ball, would be slowed down significantly by the air resistance.

Answer (score 1):

In a radial field, the center of gravity is closer to the central body than the center of mass.  This effect is enhanced in an object of lower density. When measuring the acceleration of the center of mass, the lower density object (of the same total mass) should feel a greater force (assuming no friction).